# ag-grid: update row on editor-cell-input-change

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have the following usecase: when the value inside an input-cell changes to a positive number, I want the entire row to be marked.

For marking I use:

```
rowClassRules: {'ag-row-mark': (params) => {/*if positive return boolean*/})},
```

and my css applies a style to `.ag-row-mark`-rows.

Now my problem is, that function above is getting called only when I stop editing my EditorCell. But I want params-updates of relevant rows every time when a value changes, not just when the user presses ESC/ENTER or I call `.stopEditing()`.

So are my only options

- Not using an EditorCell. I do it only for performance reasons anyway, I could also have normal CellRenderers with `<input>`, but they would cause so many listeners being active in my table.
- on every EditorCell-model change to stop editing and start editing the same cell with the new value again

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found no good solution after all, but a good workaround for me was to set rows as selected or unselected from inside the editorcell, when the input changed. This always triggers an event on the row instantly and not just when you finish editing the row.

Of course you also have to disable the regular selection handling (when a row gets clicked). For this use in gridOptions: `suppressRowClickSelection: true`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using cellValueChanged() on gridOptions() ? . This api will get triggered each and every time a cell value is changed. You can create a listener for this event and do comparisons as you wish. The params will hold oldValue as well newValue.